# Get value of pipeline "name" into PowerShell command in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-yaml-pipelines

My `azure-pipeline.yml` sets a special magical variable called `name` that causes the pipeline name to be set.

I want to use this value inside a PowerShell script to put this value into a text file as a setting.

```
variables:
  System.Debug: true
  versionNumber: '0.0.0' 
  namePrefix: 'yml_$(versionNumber).'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  tag: '-yml-$(versionNumber)'
  publishBuildArtifactsSubfolder: 'yml\$(Build.Repository.Name)_yml_$(versionNumber).'

name: ${{ variables['namePrefix']}}$(Build.BuildId)

steps:
# Find and replace in files. PowerShell because bash isn't available.
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Set version number in environment.*.ts
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        Write-Host "Build.DefinitionName is $(Build.DefinitionName)"
        Write-Host "env-name is $($env:name)"
        Write-Host "name is $($name)"

#Get-ChildItem 'environment.*.ts' -Recurse | ForEach {
#  (Get-Content $_ | ForEach  { $_ -replace '[[name]]', '${Build.DefinitionName}' }) | Set-Content $_
#}
```

Is it possible to get the value of `name` inside the PowerShell script? How? (Is this documented anywhere?)

**Workaround**

It appears to be impossible to get the special `name` thing, therefore set a variable with the same value.

```
variables:
  System.Debug: true
  versionNumber: '0.0.0' 
  namePrefix: 'yml_$(versionNumber).'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  tag: '-yml-$(versionNumber)'
  publishBuildArtifactsSubfolder: 'yml\$(Build.Repository.Name)_yml_$(versionNumber).'
  name: ${{ variables['namePrefix']}}$(Build.BuildId)

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        Write-Host "name is $($name)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `name` it's a [pre-defined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) `Build.BuildNumber`, so just use `$(Build.BuildNumber)`.